# Mock chain call in Mockito causes NullPointerException or WrongTypeOfReturnValue

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to mock this call:

```
requestTelemetryContext.getHttpRequestTelemetry().getContext().getOperation()
```

So I tried that:

```
OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext(null);
RequestTelemetryContext requestTelemetryContext = mock(RequestTelemetryContext.class);
when(requestTelemetryContext.getHttpRequestTelemetry().getContext().getOperation()).thenReturn(operationContext); //causes java.lang.NullPointerException
```

but that gives me
`java.lang.NullPointerException`.

So modified it into:

```
    OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext(null);
    RequestTelemetryContext requestTelemetryContext = mock(RequestTelemetryContext.class);
    RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry();
    when(requestTelemetryContext.getHttpRequestTelemetry()).thenReturn(requestTelemetry);
    when(requestTelemetryContext.getHttpRequestTelemetry().getContext().getOperation()).thenReturn(operationContext);
```

that gives me:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
> OperationContext cannot be returned by getHttpRequestTelemetry()
> getHttpRequestTelemetry() should return RequestTelemetry
> *** If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on. Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
>
> 1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.    Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency
>    testing.
> 2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies -
>
>    - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

I do not understand why it can't just mock the whole chain call and I am not trying to return `OperationContext` by `getHttpRequestTelemetry` like it states in the error.

EDIT:
I've tried suggested approach:

```
OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext(null);

RequestTelemetryContext requestTelemetryContext = mock(RequestTelemetryContext.class);
RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = mock(RequestTelemetry.class);
TelemetryContext telemetryContext = mock(TelemetryContext.class);

when(requestTelemetryContext.getHttpRequestTelemetry()).thenReturn(requestTelemetry);
when(requestTelemetry.getContext()).thenReturn(telemetryContext);
when(telemetryContext.getOperation()).thenReturn(operationContext);
ThreadContext.setRequestTelemetryContext(requestTelemetryContext);
```

unfortunately that line `RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = mock(RequestTelemetry.class);` causes:

> Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
>
> - final class

so i need to find a way to mock final class.

Comment: May be you will manage to construct proper instance of RequestTelemetry class without mocking?

Comment: Tried that, but I can't setup it's context as it is done by the protected method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the mock at each stage of your call chain, and each mock should return the next mock object e.g.

```
a().b().c().d()
```

so a() should return a mock, which is configured to return a mock b etc.

```
when(a()).thenReturn(mockA);
when(mockA.b()).thenReturn(mockB);
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, I tried that approach, however next problem arose, I've edited the question at the bottom.

Comment: PowerMock May be of use here if you can’t wrap that object in a non-final wrapper

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues here. the first one is with the mock of chained operations (`requestTelemetryContext.getHttpRequestTelemetry().getContext().getOperation()`). to solve this without mocking every class in the middle, you can use `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` when mocking:

```
OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext(null);
RequestTelemetryContext requestTelemetryContext = mock(RequestTelemetryContext.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
when(requestTelemetryContext.getHttpRequestTelemetry().getContext().getOperation()).thenReturn(operationContext);
```

The second issue is that mockito cannot mock final classes - this is I'm afraid not solvable, you can't mock a final class

Comment: Found that before in the documentation, didn't behave the way it's documented, it failed.

Comment: I suspect because of that regarding RequestTelemetry class:
`Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class`

Comment: which of the classes is final?

Comment: @NirLevy , `RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = mock(RequestTelemetry.class);` fails due to Final class problem.

Comment: @Yoda - saw your edit now, I edited the answer accordingly